# zmq connection to a script opened with subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, zeromq, pyzmq

I have a rather complicated socket ( ZeroMQ - **`REQ/REP`** ) based python program that I want to verify is working by running a simple socket script on the same machine.

The test script is something along these lines.

```
import subprocess
import zmq
import json

# ...

for call, response in zip(test_calls, expected_responses):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'main.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVTIMEO, 1000)
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:8084")

    socket.send_string(json.dumps(call))
    r = json.loads(socket.recv_string())

    assert r == response

    p.terminate()
    socket.close()
```

(Probably worth noting, it's actually implemented as tests in nose2 using such, but I felt that was beyond the scope of this question and would really complicate the sample. This pretty much sums up what's happening inside the tests).

85% of the time, this will work, everything will pass. Whooho! The other 15% of the time, I get an `zmq.error.Again: Resource temporarily unavailable` on the line `r = json.loads(socket.recv_string())` (and if I didn't have `zmq.RCVTIMEO` set it would just hang).

Wondering if it was a timing process (subprocess couldn't start/stop in time) I put a few `time.sleep()` calls around the place but it didn't seem to do anything.

I put a catch after the socket section and `pdb`'d in, checking the `stdout` of the python subprocess. I have a few `print` statements in the application that print to `stdout` every call and response over the sockets, but it didn't receive any input, and so of course the `recv` is going to timeout.

I've never had these kinds of problems with zmq before, so I'm thinking it might have something to do with the usage of subprocesses like this. Does anyone know what the problem might be and how to fix it?

Thanks.

---

**Update:** So it looks like the processes aren't terminating (despite the use of a `signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, close_app)` signal in the main application). Would this cause confusion regarding the active process to communicate with via zmq? Initially calling `p.kill()` instead of `p.terminate()` seemed to do the trick, though it has still failed once or twice in the same way.

---

**Update 2:** Something that seems to be working, is calling the command `kill` directly:

```
subprocess.call(['kill', str(p.pid)])
counter = 0
while p.poll() is None:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    counter += 1
    if counter > 20:
        p.kill()
```

Which seems to gracefully shut it down in most cases.

Comment: Can you confirm, that the general scenario works with a "non-subprocess" mode ( a standalone process ) of the **`zmq.REP`** peer that **`.bind()`**-s on the same **`tcp://localhost:8084`** ?

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "Wondering if it was a timing process"? please?

Comment: @Avv oh wow, this is very old, can't even remember the context in which I asked this. I may have been referring to race conditions or something like that. Sorry, but not totally sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What the problem might be

could be related with the not posted code inside the said sub-process, which causes the observed behaviour initiated during a sub-process enforced termination ( incl. it's other resources, managed in a smart and very feature-rich multi-threaded **`zmq.Context( n_IO_threads = 1 )`** instance, out of your sight & within just a limited a-priori coded / executed controls ).

### Consider `{SIGTERM|SIGKILL|...}` rather an emergency brake,
panic buttons,
not a wise solution in distributed-system design

Once entered a distributed-system design, one shall rather forget to use context-less tools alike `SIGTERM` et al, but had better rather incorporate one's own, soft-signalling, control-plane into the newly designed distributed-system infrastructure.

This helps the "remote"-agent behave in accord with an actual context of such soft-signal and allows to perform ( under your full algorithmic control ) all the necessary safe-guarding, resources clean-up and pre-termination duties, so as to finally gracefully clean exit afterwards.

I may sound as old-fashioned in this, but rather always keep sockets explicitly instructed to **`.close()`** before your code finally goes to instruct all your `zmq.Context()` instances to **`.term()`**. This is reported not to be necessary, but doing resources-handling clean and fair is IMHO a fair duty in distributed-system's design / implementation.

No exceptions, no excuses.

### Damned forgotten zero in `ZMQ_LINGER`

One example, that is worth mentioning is the **`ZeroMQ API`** default value for a **`ZMQ_LINGER`** parameter, which if not set otherwise has a default value of **`0`** and that means, once such `ZeroMQ`-socket instance get instructed ( explicitly or implicitly ) to **`.close()`** and happens to still have a `ZMQ_LINGER == 0`, the socket-endpoint will **`BLOCK`** till all messages from the counterparty buffer get delivered, which may cause your distributed processing hang-up without any chance to resolve such dead-lock ex-post, if not have been pre-set correctly not to wait for pending messages forever.

A newer `pyzmq` documentation explicitly warns not to `.destroy()` a `zmq.Context` instance ( and blindly let get sockets `.close()`-d by an authoritatively issued `.destroy()`, which is ouside one's own code-control )

> **`ctx.destroy( linger = None )`**
>   Close all sockets associated with this context, and then terminate the context. If `linger` is specified, the `LINGER` sockopt of the sockets will be set prior to closing.
>   **Warning**
>   `.destroy` involves calling `zmq_close()`, which is NOT threadsafe. If there are active sockets in other threads, **this must not be called** <sub>( which advice, most probably, the `SIGTERM` & al will ignore, wouldn't it? )</sub>

so even a few more reasons not to rely on `SIGTERM` devils' service.

### A port in use

Plus, it takes some time to release the occupied transport-class resources. So, having a code that has just released an **`IP:port`** does not mean another instance / process / thread may right jump in and snap the very same port, without some O/S-related latencies. Rather check your resources re-use / release policy in this aspect too ( I would dare to risk any risk of blocking in this area and use some port-address pool to rotate and **`FILO`**-queueing, so as to at least defer any potential re-use case, until a reasonable O/S-related latencies have pretty well expired -- IMHO preventing a blocking-state is much better than to ex-post handle exceptions on blocking states ).

### `.bind()` before `.connect()`

is another such issue. Once your **`subprocess.Popen(...)`** starts, it takes some time before the O/S services launch and make the sub-process to start to breathe on it's own.

If your first process, already active and executing has reached the `.connect()`, before the spawned subprocess instance has ever got to it's `.bind()`, the distributed-system will choke.

Setup/dismantle round-trip-times are not reducible to zero. Resources are not disposables. There are some system-related maintenance & sharing overhead associated with using thereof.

### Finally `.recv_string()` may and does raise a `ZMQError EAGAIN`

in cases, there is not yet any message ready in the local-node to get it retrieved by any `.recv*()` method, be it a `{.recv|.recv_string|.recv_json|&al}` in a `flags = zmq.NOBLOCK` mode.

Comment: Hey thanks. This was a really useful answer in identifying the issue. From what I can tell, it was a combination of the delays you mention releasing ports and some other problems terminating the application. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Glad it helped you move ahead. Keep walking, SCB!